# Multiple Web API projects, one localhost URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, localhost

I have two AWS Serverless .NET Core Web API projects which I want to be part of the *same* API. I have split the API into multiple projects because I want to be able to deploy different parts independently.

I also have an MVC project which calls to this API. I want to be able to specify a single API base URL in my MVC config but have the combined controllers of all the API projects available at that one endpoint.

Is there a way to accomplish this when running locally? Ideally I want to be able to run both of my API projects and have them use the same localhost URL. I also want to be able to debug both API projects. I've done some Googling and looking around on SO but nothing seems to have helped me so far.

Comment: Docker compose with 2 app containers + nginx container for example. Or using Http.sys (formerly know as WebListener - Its windows only). Or any arbitrary local reverse proxy of your choice

Comment: I've tried adding `.UseHttpSys()` to my `IWebHostBuilder` and then ran both projects but I just get 502.5 errors now. Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: Which port? Low port number require Admin right or adding Acl via netsh

Comment: `.UseHttpSys(options => { options.UrlPrefixes.Add("http://localhost:5000/"); })` I've set this on both projects. The two applications still launch with http://localhost:63267/ and http://localhost:63268/ though.

Comment: I've turned std logs on in web.config and I have three logs for each project, all of which say something like "Overriding endpoints added to UrlPrefixes since PreferHostingUrls is set to true. Binding to address(es) 'http://localhost:15504' instead." but each with a different port. I've tried setting `PreferHostingUrls` to true and false and it always happens.

Comment: I am curious. Why do you want to deploy different parts independently? What's the benefit? If they are independent, why not have separate URLs?

Comment: It's going to be a big, complicated API and I just want to be able to break it down and deploy different parts on their own. That way I limit the amount of risk and testing required after each deployment.